# "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: pandas

This looks like a bug in `pandas.Series.all` to me (`df` is a Pandas `DataFrame` object, and `pd` is shorthand for `pandas`):

```
In [18]: df.foo.apply(lambda x: x.startswith(u'bar').head()
Out[18]:
0    True
1    False
2    True
3    True
4    False
Name: foo

In [19]: (df.baz == u'frobozz').head()
Out[19]: 
0    False
1    False
2    True
3    True
4    False
Name: baz

In [20]: (type(Out[20]), type(Out[19]))
Out[20]: (pandas.core.series.Series, pandas.core.series.Series)

In [21]: pd.Series.all(Out[18], Out[19])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-310-d132f431d45f> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.Series.all(Out[18], Out[19])

/home/jones/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    276     @Appender(func.__doc__)
    277     def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 278         result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    279         if isinstance(result, np.ndarray) and result.ndim == 0:
    280             # return NumPy type

/home/jones/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.pyc in _all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     28 def _all(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
     29     return um.logical_and.reduce(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out,
---> 30                                  keepdims=keepdims)                                                                                                                       
     31
     32 def _count_reduce_items(arr, axis):

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

What's going on?

Comment: +1 I did not know you could use Out[14] etc. as variables.

Comment: @AndyHayden: It's an idea that ipython borrowed from Mathematica (which, in my opinion, sets the standard for graphical interfaces, of any kind, and has been doing so for the last 20 years or so).  BTW, just like `Out` can be treated as an array, so can `In`, although its contents are not as useful.  One (admittedly farfetched) situation in which `In` could be handy would be, for example, if `In[10]` is a complicated expression involving `x`, let's call it `E(x)` for short, and the value of `x` has changed since `In[10]` was evaluated (to produce what's now in `Out[10]`)....

Comment: Then one could run `eval(In[10])` to get the updated value for `E(x)`.  IOW, `In` can be thought of as an "addressable" form of one's interaction history, one that that allows one to get to a particular input expression without having to do a linear (reverse) traversal of the history with the up-arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a bug to me, but I don't know what you think `pd.Series.all(Out[18], Out[19])` does.

```
>>> pd.Series.all?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<unbound method Series.all>
File:       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/core/series.py
Definition: pd.Series.all(self, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
a.all(axis=None, out=None)

Returns True if all elements evaluate to True.
```

You're using the version from the class, so the first argument is being interpreted as the instance, and the second as the axis.  `pandas` is trying to convert the second `Series` you're passing to an integer to make sense of it as an axis, which can't work if the array has length > 1.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc, pd.Series.all appears to only take one Series object. Try this -

```
pd.Series.all(Out[18].append(Out[19]))
```